# Identify song name and artist

Tags: history, musicology

I think it was in 70s or 80s a young woman from U.S. went to work for awhile on an island, maybe Jamaica. When she was ready to return I believe there was a problem taking her earnings with her so she spent the money by renting a studio and recording a song that became a big hit, maybe pop category.

Comment: Hi bgn. This type of question should be asked on the [Stack Exchange Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Thank you, I just submitted it but have to wait 40 mins to post again.

Comment: You might be waiting much longer time for an answer. 40 mins is less than a single episode of a TV drama

Comment: I just meant it wouldn't let me post on the Music Fans site right away, apparently only 1 question allowed every 40 mins. I don't mind how long it takes to get an answer, have been trying to find it on my own, one of those mysteries that started driving me crazy.